# How to return TRUE if matrix contains any NAs?

Tags: r, matrix, na

I wish query a matrix object and return a simple `TRUE`/`FALSE` answer if a matrix contains any NAs. So, if there are no NAs present you would get `FALSE`.

`is.na(my.matrix)` will tell me element-by-element if NAs are present, but I don't know how to sum up the results into a single answer. `na.fail()` looks like a better bet, but I'm still not sure how to extract a straightforward `TRUE`/`FALSE` answer.

Comment: `any(is.na(my.matrix))`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Ananda Mahto pointed out, `any(is.na(my.matrix))` does the trick.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to find the *number* of occurrences of NA then try `sum(is.na(my.matrix))`.